# pass params in ngModel angular 2

Tags: angular

I try pass params variable `item.audutModel` in `[(ngModel)]` and catch value of `[(ngModel)]` by `(ngModelChange)="AddAdults(item.audutModel)"` but in `(ngModelChange)="AddAdults(item.audutModel)"` it understand `item.audutModel` is name Model not params . Sorry for my English. If you can't understand please ask in comment.

my code :

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]=item.audutModel (ngModelChange)="AddAdults(item.audutModel)">
    <ion-option value="1">1 người</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="2">2 người</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="3">3 người</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Comment: What is the current behavior and what is the expected behavior?

Comment: try to change `AddAdults($event)`

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: If you don't want to use the select box in a form, you can do the following instead:

```
<ion-select [value]="item.audutModel" (change)="AddAdults(item.audutModel)">
    <ion-option value="1">1 người</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="2">2 người</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="3">3 người</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

This assigns the value of `item.audutModel` as the select box's value and listens for the onChange event of the select box.

**Old answer**:

You shouldn't add the `()` around ngModel if you're already handling `ngModelChange`. Also, you'll need quotemarks around `item.audutModel`

Like so

```
<ion-select [ngModel]="item.audutModel" (ngModelChange)="AddAdults(item.audutModel)">
    <ion-option value="1">1 người</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="2">2 người</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="3">3 người</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

The parantheses add an event listener for the ngModelChange event that sets the value of the variable to the changed value.

Comment: if use [ngModel]="item.audutModel" i can't pass variable

Comment: @ĐứcLê If so, you shouldn't use ngModel. You should assign to `[value]` and listen for `(change)`. Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

Well I would use it this way. I hope this will be helpful to someone.

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedKey" (ngModelChange)="doSomethingWithSelected()">
   <ion-option value="1">1 option</ion-option>
   <ion-option value="2">2 option</ion-option>
   <ion-option value="3">3 option</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

**selectedKey** is a variable which gets selected value, so on **ngModelChange** event you can just use method without any parameters. Just use **selectedKey** inside it. This variable will hold selected value.

If you have any more questions regarding ngModel, you should look into [ngModel documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html).

About not using **[()]** (bannana notation), for ngModel you should use both brackets. That way you can also set selected value in select box.

> [] - Read only [()] - Read/Write